# Issue running jupyter notebook via wls

Tags: jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Installed WSL on Windows 10.
Installed Anaconda according to the Anaconda documentation with the following commands:

```
bash Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh
source ~/.bashrc
```

You can see the '(base)' in the beginning of each command input line, indicating the conda is activated.
Then I run jupyter notebook by typing:

```
jupyter notebook
```

Then I see the following changes as shown in the screen record.
Briefly, the WSL terminal window showed some information very quickly, but is changed to the windows powershell window before you could even tell the information that showed up. I know those information should contain a file and url for opening the jupyter notebook in the web browser. But they flashed out so quickly. Does anyone know why this happens?

Here is a dynamic graph of the Screen record of this issue:
[image: screen_record.gif]

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
1. Wait for a bit more time on the windows cmd and the jupyter notebook running information will show up, where includes the url to open jupyter notebook in the web browser.

OR

2. Open up another wsl terminal, activate the same environment and type `jupyter notebook list`, which will show the current running jupyter notebook server. The url is also can be found there.